# Phalcon: How to get parameter in url using routing

Tags: routes, phalcon

I want to get the "q" parameter value for urls like this:

```
http://api.domain.com/artist?callback=jQuery1710976531726308167_1400000891029&q=thanh&_=1400000895743
```

How to do that using routing in Phalcon? I try this but not matching:

```
$app->get("/artist?callback={callback:(.*)}&q={q:(.*)}&_={_:(.*)}", function ($q) {
    //my logic code
}
```

or

```
$app->get("/artist?callback=jQuery1710976531726308167_1400000891029&q=thanh&_=1400000895743", function () {
    //my logic code
}
```

Comment: Routes must not include query parameters, only $app->get("/artist") is needed.

Comment: Great! It worked. Thank you, twistedtra.

Comment: You can use this, 
$this->request->get('artist');

Answer (score 1):

In Phalcon, you use the Phalcon\Http\Request Object to retrieve your query string params.  If you are trying to define routes for Phalcon's Micro Framework, your route should be defined like this:

```
$app->get("/artist", function () {
    $request = new Phalcon\Http\Request();
    $q = $request->get('q');
    echo $q;
});
```

You do not define the route with the query string arguments. Your route will match the above based on the part preceding the question mark in the url.  Also, the passing of arguments into the anonymous function handling the get request is for REST arguments in the URL pattern.  Such as:

```
$app->get("/artist/{name}", function ($name) {
    echo $name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways, something like this:

**Way 1**: Using **Get** parameters

```
$this->request->get('artist');
```

**Way 2**: Using **Router**

in router:

```
$router->add("/artist/id/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-])", array( 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'artist', 'name' => 'abc' ));
```

in Controller:

```
$id = $this->dispatcher->getParam("name");
```

Hope this will work fine.